# Three js distorted image around edges of view

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a three js scene in a banner like format (970px X 250px)

The scene setup is as follows:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set(4,3,0);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize( container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight );
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
container.prepend( renderer.domElement );
```

Where `container` has a width and height of 970 px by 250px

But as you can see in the image below around the edges of the scene it all gets distorted.
clearly visible by the sand texture, center looks good edges (left and right) looks horrible.
[image]

Is there a way to fix this or am I missing something?
If more information is needed please let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: This is normal, that's just [how perspective works](https://spaceindaver.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/wntlines.jpg). To fix it, you can move the camera further away, then zoom in.

Comment: Maybe use an orthographic camera, https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera